# How to build an external class library for use with a solution in a CI Pipeline in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I've requested to my Team Lead that we start integrating a CI/CD pipeline into most, if not all, of our projects. Our newest project relies heavily on our own, external class library that is referenced in the solution ; it is under "Dependencies" as a project reference.

The project runs fine when I build it in my machine using Visual Studio 2019, and before we needed to integrate an external library, it would build and release fine using our Azure DevOps pipelines.

However, with the addition of an external class library, when I try to run a build through Azure DevOps, I get the following error:

> The project file  ....csproj was not found.

I fully understand why it can't find it - because I need to pull in the external class library and build that first! There doesn't seem to be a lot of online material (not that I could find anyway!) that describes solutions to this other than "use nuget" ; unfortunately, it is a requirement from my Team Lead that this is not a route we go down - which has lead to a long couple of days!

With this in mind, I can't find another way to do this in Azure DevOps. I have looked into some sort of PowerShell command but to no avail thus far.

Has anyone run into this issue before with external class libraries in DevOps and can give me advice on the best way to approach it?

Comment: I know there is a direct recommendation from your TeamLeader, and maybe there are some corner cases, which are making this decision appropriate. However, in 99.99% this is a terrible idea. You will move a dll-dependency-hell from local machine to the CI solution. Recently, I joined the new team as an Architect and someone in the past decided to have direct dependencies in CI builds. And right now one of my first decision is to migrate all these direct references to NuGet because CI/CD is a nightmare here.

Comment: You are using Azure DevOps. You have a build-in internal Nuget server (additional license required) and build-in steps to create NuGet on CI. Publish csproj as NuGet by AzureDevOps is one-hour-task (or one-day if you are doing it for the first time). Maybe you are able to convince Team Leader with good arguments.

Comment: Okay, I guess I'll have to compile a little doc to try to convince him! His biggest concern is security and being able to easily update the NuGet packages etc. as the class library gets updated over time. Are these things all okay by using NuGet packages?

Comment: if you will use Azure DevOps Nuget Servier which is internal for your project the level of security will be enough. However each developer need to have an additional license for it. Cheaper alternative is for instance https://www.myget.org/.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! There's definitely not a free way of doing this? As I'm sure you can imagine, presenting the Team Lead with the option he isn't keen on which also incurs a cost isn't going to go down to well!

Comment: Actually it is you can build and run your own nuget server. It is easy to achieve but less secure: https://nicolaiarocci.com/how-to-build-and-deploy-a-private-nuget-server-on-iis-or-azure/

You need to backup all nuget packages inside your server to not lose the work after crash.

In my opinion, having NuGet server for organizations in these times is a standard - like Git instead of SVN or TFS as a default repository.

Comment: My bad - Azure Artifacts is cheaper than myget and you can start for free. First 2 GB are free:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/

Comment: Perfect, thanks very much for your help! Do you want to write an answer that illustrates these points so I can accept it please?

Comment: yeah sure, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking in 99,99% cases keeping a direct reference to the project is not a good idea. You can end up with really unmaintainable CI/CD logic and/or with dll versions mismatches during deployments. Actually I am an Architect in the project where I tried to fix that issue by migrating all dependencies to the NuGet server.

### Azure Artifacts

You mentioned, that you are using Azure DevOps as main CI/CD tool, so this is a great opportunity to introduce [Azure Artifacts](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/devops/artifacts/) as **internal** nuget server which is a part of Azure DevOps. For the first 2 GB it is free, here you have [pricing details](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/azure-devops-services/).

### Alternatives

If for some reason you cant use Azure Artifacts, I recommend some alernatives:

- MyGet
- ProGet
- Own nuget server

More information about alternatives you can find in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview).